# Polar coordinates clarification why is the radians portion wrong despite right angle triangle? Converting $(x,y) = (-6, 2\sqrt{3})$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

Trying to plot polar coordinates and got all the right steps until the end where I need to evaluate $\arctan \frac{\sqrt{3}}{-3} = \frac{\pi}{-6}$, but that puts the point on the wrong quadrant. Where did I go wrong?

[image]

Comment: The formula $\theta=\arctan(y/x)$ doesn't hold in this case since $x<0$. See the function [ATan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Comment: What do you mean, doesn't arctan x resolve for all points of x including negative? (ie. arctan(-1) = $\frac{-\pi}{4}$?) (Graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sfthrl6gn4)

Comment: $\tan$ is not invertible in $[0,2\pi)$ (or $[-\pi,\pi)$ depending on your convention), therefore your formula doesn't always hold. You can still use your formula, but then you need to add a suitable integer multiple of $\pi$ (note the periodicity of $\tan$) to get the result to the correct quadrant. With this, you get that $\theta=-\pi/6+\pi=5\pi/6$.

Comment: Thanks @projectilemotion, but calculator(Ti-84) still evaluates them..? Why.
Also if arctan doesn't evaluate, are there other trig functions that don't evaluate while the calculator still does?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me: $\arctan(x)$ is also defined for negative $x$ (and hence should evaluate to a number on your TI-84). What I meant was that the formula for the angle is not always $\arctan(y/x)$. In particular, that formula only holds on the 1st and 4th quadrant (assuming you assume angles go from $-\pi$ to $\pi$). For the quadrant you are considering, the formula for the angle is $$\theta=\arctan(y/x)+\pi.$$

Comment: I see, so you mean y = arctan x is valid between $(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{-\pi}{2})$ ?

Comment: Why can't we use arctan? it seems like the value $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{-3}$ is between $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ and $ \frac{\pi}{2}$ ....? It falls in the 4th quadrant of the unit circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse tangent function gives an angle $\theta$ satisfying $-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ (the *right* half of the circle when we measure angles in standard position). Sure enough,
$$
\theta = \arctan \biggl( -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \biggr) 
= -\arctan \biggl( \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \biggr) 
= -\frac{\pi}{6} 
$$
lies on that interval and has the correct tangent value. However, there are many—*infinitely many*—angles that have that tangent value. In fact, there are two different angles every time you go around the circle! The upshot: you can add or subtract $\pi$ to $\theta$ as many times as you like without changing the value of its tangent.

Look at the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the point: it’s in the second quadrant, i.e. $\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \pi$.

With a little bit of effort you can see that
$$
\theta + \pi = \frac{5\pi}{6} 
$$
gives an angle that lands in the second quadrant, so this is an appropriate angle coordinate for a positive radial coordinate.

Comment: thanks but doesn't $\frac{5\pi}{6}$ also have infinitely many angles with the tangent value..? ie. when ever $2\pi(n) + \frac{5\pi}{6}$ where n goes to infinity.

Comment: Yes, which is why the angle coordinate in polar coordinates is not unique unless we agree on some restriction such as $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$.

Comment: ok so only going through the circle once. Why can't tangent by on the right side of the circle btw (ie. on the 2nd quadrant)? Wouldn't adding $\pi$ distort it's angle? ie. $\frac{-\pi}{6} = 150 ^{\circ} $ and $\frac{5\pi}{6} = 330 ^{\circ}$ and those aren't equivalent angles..?

Comment: In other words, $(r, \theta) = \bigl( 4\sqrt{3}, \tfrac{5\pi}{6} \bigr)$ and $(r, \theta) = \bigl( 4\sqrt{3}, \tfrac{17\pi}{6} \bigr)$ describe the same point. Even $(r, \theta) = \bigl( -4\sqrt{3}, -\tfrac{\pi}{6} \bigr)$ does!

Answer (score 5):

I would do it solving a *system* of linear equations:
\begin{cases}
\cos\theta=-\dfrac{6}{4\sqrt 3}=-\dfrac{\sqrt 3}2 \iff \theta \equiv \pm \dfrac{5\pi} 6\pmod{2\pi},\\
\sin\theta=\dfrac{2\sqrt 3}{4\sqrt 3}=\dfrac12\iff \theta \equiv  \dfrac\pi 6,\dfrac{5\pi}6\pmod{2\pi}.
\end{cases}
So the solution is $\;\theta\equiv\dfrac{5\pi} 6\pmod{2\pi}$, and on the interval $[0,2\pi)$, it is $\;\dfrac{5\pi}6$.

Comment: That can't be right. $(-6,2\sqrt3)$ is in the second quadrant, so $\tfrac\pi2 \leq \theta \leq \pi$.

Comment: @kahen: You're right. I forgot the minus sign in front of $6$. I'll fix it within seconds

Comment: This seems very unintuitive and a scenic route to get there. Why can't we use arctan? it seems like the value $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{-3}$ is between $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ and $ \frac{\pi}{2}$ ....?

Comment: @nvs0000: First it is geometrically intuitive, with the trigonometric circle. Second,  one visualises instantly in which quadrant the solution is.

Answer (score 0):

Computed result is $-30^\circ$.

Note that $\tan (180^\circ + x) = \tan x$.

Note also that $\theta =\arctan \left(- \dfrac ab\right)$ is equal to $\arctan \left( \dfrac {-a}b\right)$ or $\arctan \left( \dfrac a{-b}\right)$ and we have to choose the right one, the one that matches the original given.